# Min and Max Start And Stop times for daily times sql

Tags: sql, date, time

i am on a project at the moment to create a report that gets employees Start and stop times, lunch breaks, and a total of hours worked each day.
Having an issue with getting min and max times for a day of records. so what is happening is people have more than one record etc, leaving for an hour or so then returning. this makes the report get really messy. i have looked around and cant find a solution, any help would be great.
here is what i have so far:

```
 select E.FullName, EL.DateTimeStart, EL.DateTimeStop, E.EmployeeStatusCode, EL.ExtraMinutes,
           Sum(El.ShiftTime /60.0 + (ExtraMinutes / 60.0)) as TotalHoursWorked   
    FROM       dbo.Employee AS E
    INNER JOIN dbo.employeelog AS EL 
    ON         E.EmployeeKey = EL.EmployeeKey   
    where      E.EmployeeStatusCode = 'P' 
    GROUP BY   FullName, EL.DateTimeStart, EL.DateTimeStop, E.EmployeeStatusCode, EL.ExtraMinutes
    having     Sum(El.ShiftTime /60.0 + (ExtraMinutes / 60.0)) > 0
    ORDER BY   FullName
```

This Being the Results

```
Adam    2017-05-31 07:23:59.593 2017-05-31 07:24:08.923 P   0   0.016666

Adam    2017-06-01 07:00:10.557 2017-06-01 16:03:31.430 P   -30 8.550000

Adam    2017-06-02 07:00:26.877 2017-06-02 12:07:20.137 P   0   5.116666

Adam    2017-06-02 12:49:15.633 2017-06-02 16:13:59.393 P   -30 2.900000

Adam    2017-06-05 07:05:21.670 2017-06-05 16:08:26.250 P   -30 8.550000

Adam    2017-06-06 07:01:42.217 2017-06-06 16:04:58.810 P   -30 8.550000

Adam    2017-06-07 06:59:38.947 2017-06-07 15:16:32.860 P   -30 7.783333
```

Comment: Give some sample data and show what do you expect based on that.

Comment: Hey mate, all i want is to get the First Start record for a day and  last finish record for a day, (Min and max times) you can see in the results that line 3 and 4 share the same date, i want this to only take the first start time and last finish time per day

Comment: Ok, but in order for us to help, you should provide data for both source table which is giving you this output. [Please read how to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/5234334)

Comment: And also mention the database/version you are working with

Comment: you just want a couple rows of data from both the source tables?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management studio 2016